# EKS: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster(Terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

Good evening.

I am facing an issue with setting up EKS with managed node groups on AWS.

The creation of the Nodegroup keeps failing with the error:

```
waiting for EKS Node Group (XXX-stage:XXX-stage) create: unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED', wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last error: i-0f1fd27c757cf9774: NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster
```

I have confirmed my security groups are properly set with
I have confirmed the roles for the cluster and the nodegroup
I have confirmed the creation of the natgateway in a public subnet and the internet gateway.
I have also confirmed that the private subnets and the gateways have been associated with the route tables.

Please what could I be missing?

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.